# Extract heading from various tags using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, scrapy

How can i extract table headings from both table types from the below html using beautiful soup

```
<body>
    <p>some other data 1</p>
    <p>Table1 heading</p>
    <div></div>
    <div>
        <div><table width="15%"><tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><p>data1_00</p></td>
                <td><p>data1_01</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>data1_10</p></td>
                <td><p>data1_11</p></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table></div>
    </div>

    <br><br>

    <div>some other data 2</div>
    <div>Table2 heading</div>
    <div>
        <div><table width="15%"><tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><p>data2_00</p></td>
                <td><p>data2_01</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>data2_10</p></td>
                <td><p>data2_11</p></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

On the first table, heading comes inside `<p>` tag and on the second table heading comes inside `<div>` tag. Also on the second table there is a blank `<div>` tag just above the table.
How to extract both table headings?

Currently i am searching for the previous `<div>` above current table using `table.find_previous('div')` and the text inside it will be saved as heading.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

htmlpage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    page = BeautifulSoup(htmlpage, "html.parser")
    all_divtables = page.find_all('table')
    for table in all_divtables:
        curr_div = table
        while True:
            curr_div = curr_div.find_previous('div')
            if len(curr_div.find_all('table')) > 0:
                continue
            else:
                heading = curr_div.text.strip()
                print(heading)
                break
```

> desired output :
>   `Table1 heading`
>   `Table2 heading`

Comment: Can you post your python code?

Comment: @Wonka, added code

Comment: can you post now your desired output? It seems better to find_all("tr"), I will wait your desired output to know what you want.

Comment: Check @Andrej Kesely answer, it seems good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `find_previous()` function with lambda parameter, that selects first previous tag which doesn't contain other table and doesn't contain empty string:

```
data = '''<body>
    <p>some other data 1</p>
    <p>Table1 heading</p>
    <div></div>
    <div>
        <div><table width="15%"><tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><p>data1_00</p></td>
                <td><p>data1_01</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>data1_10</p></td>
                <td><p>data1_11</p></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table></div>
    </div>

    <br><br>

    <div>some other data 2</div>
    <div>Table2 heading</div>
    <div>
        <div><table width="15%"><tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><p>data2_00</p></td>
                <td><p>data2_01</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>data2_10</p></td>
                <td><p>data2_11</p></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table></div>
    </div>

    <div>some other data 3</div>
    <div>Table3 heading</div>
    <div>
        <div><table width="15%"><tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><p>data2_00z</p></td>
                <td><p>data2_01z</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>data2_10z</p></td>
                <td><p>data2_11z</p></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div><table width="15%"><tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><p>data2_00x</p></td>
                <td><p>data2_01x</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>data2_10x</p></td>
                <td><p>data2_11x</p></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table></div>
    </div>

</body>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

for table in soup.select('table'):
    for i in table.find_previous(lambda t: not t.find('table') and t.text.strip() != ''):
        if i.find_parents('table'):
            continue
        print(i)
        print('*' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Table1 heading
********************************************************************************
Table2 heading
********************************************************************************
Table3 heading
********************************************************************************
```

Comment: thanks, it works for all case except, for two consecutive tables - if second table doesn't have any heading.

Comment: @Shijith updated the case when there are two consecutive tables with one heading.

Answer (score 0):

```
urldata='''<body>
    <p>some other data 1</p>
    <p>Table1 heading</p>
    <div></div>
    <div>
        <div><table width="15%"><tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><p>data1_00</p></td>
                <td><p>data1_01</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>data1_10</p></td>
                <td><p>data1_11</p></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table></div>
    </div>

    <br><br>

    <div>some other data 2</div>
    <div>Table2 heading</div>
    <div>
        <div><table width="15%"><tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><p>data2_00</p></td>
                <td><p>data2_01</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>data2_10</p></td>
                <td><p>data2_11</p></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table></div>
    </div>
</body>'''

import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

results =soup.body.findAll(text=re.compile('heading'))
for result in results:
    print(result)

**Output:-**

Table1 heading
Table2 heading
```

Comment: heading may or may not contain text `heading`.

Comment: replace text with your text

Comment: i have to use this for web scraping, so there is no exact text which i am looking for. all i know is the tag prior to table (if any) contains heading

Comment: then you can pass any heading tag like thead on findAll()
like this soup.body.findAll('thead') or any tag